# Variance of a bootstrap estimator

Tags: statistics, variance, estimation, bootstrap-sampling

Suppose we have a sample $X_1,X_2,...,X_n \sim F$, where the distribution $F$ is unknown.  Let $T_n = g(X_1,X_2,...,X_n) = \bar{X}^2$, $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X_1]$, and define the following:
$$\alpha_k = \int \left | x - \mu \right | ^k dF(x) \ \ \ \  \text{and} \ \ \ \ \hat{\alpha}_k = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left | X_i - \bar{X_n} \right |^k.$$
We can see that $\hat{\alpha}_k$ is the plug-in estimator for $\alpha_k$. Now suppose we take $B$ bootstrap samples $X_1^*, X_2^* , ..., X_n^*$ and compute $T_n^*$.  I want to show that the variance of $T_n^*$, that is, the variance of our bootstrap estimate, is
$$v_{\text{bootstrap}}(T_n^*) = \frac{4\bar{X_n}^2 \hat{\alpha}_2}{n} + \frac{4\bar{X_n} \hat{\alpha}_3}{n^2}+\frac{\hat{\alpha}_4}{n^3}.$$
In general, the variance of a bootstrap estimator $S_n^*$ with $B$ bootstrap samples is
$$v_{\text{bootstrap}} = \frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^{B}\left ( S_{n,b}^* - \frac{1}{B}\sum_{r=1}^{n}S_{n,r}^* \right )^2,$$
where $S_{n,b}^*$ is the statistic computed from the $b^{\text{th}}$ bootstrap sample.  If I use this definition and apply it to the original problem, I obtain something like

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
v_{\text{bootstrap}} &= 
\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^{B}\left ( \bar{X}_{n,b}^{*2} - \frac{1}{B}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\bar{X}_{n,r}^{*2} \right )^2 \\ &=
\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^{B}\left [ \bar{X}_{n,b}^{*4} - 2\bar{X}_{n,b}^{*2}\frac{1}{B}\sum_{r=1}^{B}\bar{X}_{n,r}^{*2} + \frac{1}{B^2}\sum_{r=1}^{B}\bar{X}_{n,r}^{*2}\right  ] .\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
From here, I don't see anything I can do to get a nicer form.  So although this should simplify to $v_{\text{bootstrap}}(T_n^*),$ I am thinking this is probably not the best approach.  Another approach that I thought of was conditioning.  We have
$$\mathrm{Var}[\bar{X}^{*2}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{Var}[\bar{X}^{*2} | X_1, X_2, ... , X_n]] +\mathrm{Var}[\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}^{*2} | X_1, X_2, ... , X_n]].$$
This seems more computable.  The bootstrap distribution is as follows.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & \mathbb{P} (X^* = x )\\ \hline
X_1 & 1/n \\ \hline
X_2 & 1/n \\ \hline
\vdots & \vdots  \\ \hline
X_n & 1/n \\ \hline
\end{array}
From this, the expected value and variance of $\bar{X}^*$ come easily, but the squared term in $\bar{X}^{*2}$ is what is tripping me up.

Does anyone have any ideas or possible solutions?  Thanks.